# Android Studio - Google-Play-Services - com.google.android.gms.empty

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am experiencing issues with creating a project that uses google play services in Android Studio. I am able to import com.google.android.gms, but nothing else. after I hit . after gms, I get the options of importing * or R. There is no option for GoogleMap, GooglePlayServicesUtil, etc.

I have tried quite a few different things, and have scrapped the project multiple times and started from scratch. At first I attempted to import the google-play-services_lib as a module into the project, but that did nothing, and after reading for a while I found that this was the incorrect way to do it.

I have since tried this (which seems to be the correct way) but it still is not working.

Code from Gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
}
```

As I mentioned, I do not have any error with the compile line. In fact, 'intellisense' detects com.google.android.gms. Just nothing after that, so I can't import anything useful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been banging my head against a wall with this. It would help to have a fresh set of eyes.

Thanks!

Comment: are you on 0.3 or 0.3.1?

Answer (score 2):

It needs to `Sync project with gradle files` everytime you edit `build.gradle` so AndroidStudio can fetch the changes.

[image: Sync project with gradle files]

Note, that your build tools are outdated:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Google Play services Integration.**

**Step 1:**

```
SDK manager->Tools Update this

1.Google play services
2.Android Support Repository
```

**Step 2:**

```
chance in build.gradle 
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.+'
}
```

**Step 3:**

```
 android.manifest.xml
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

**Step 4:**

```
Sync project file with grandle.
wait for few minute.
```

**Step 5:**

```
File->Project Structure find error with red bulb images,click on go to add dependencies select your app module.
Save
```

Please put comment if you have require help.
Happy coding.